# Why does exit(0) in TRY loop result in an exception being thrown?

Tags: python-2.7, exception

Consider the following example:

```
try:
     print "Try this."
     exit(0)
except:
     print "Failed."
     exit(1)
```

When this simple example is executed, the following is printed to stdout:

```
Try this.
Failed.
```

Forgive me if there is an obvious answer or if this has already been asked, but why does `exit(0)` (which should give me a clean exit) throw an exception?

I tried using a `try: except:` loop in an actual use-case script, and found that the script would exit(1) even when the `try` condition says to `exit(0).`

So I guess `exit(0)` is throwing a(n hidden?) exception of some sort, but why?  It doesn't show the traceback (such as when CTRL + C is used to generate a KeyboardInterrupt exception), and results in unexpected behavior such as in my case when I'm expecting a 0 return and end up with a 1 return.

Is an exception (any exception) the *only* way to exit a python script?

Comment: A lot of information about this shows up if you just Google `python exit`.

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry, guess I'm blind today.  Flagged as duplicate.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

The exception being raised here is `SystemExit` Exception. Hence, if you try:

```
try:
     print "Try this."
     exit(0)
except SystemExit:
     pass
except:
     print "Failed."
     exit(1)
```

Output is:

```
Try this.
```

To prevent this, you can call `os._exit()` to directly exit, without throwing an exception:

```
import os
try:
     print "Try this."
     os._exit(0)
except SystemExit:
     pass
except:
     print "Failed."
     os._exit(1)
```

Quoting [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112):

`os._exit` skips finally blocks, context manager `__exit__`s, exit handlers, and other important cleanup, so outside of a few highly specific cases (I believe most of them involve fork), it's not a good idea to use it.

Comment: `except not SystemExit` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Okay, please help me out. I meant dont test that exception...

Comment: There's no way to specify "all exceptions but this one". The closest you can get is catching all exceptions with `except BaseException as e` and then un-catching the one you don't want with `if isinstance(e, SystemExit): raise` (with no argument to `raise`).

Comment: How about my editted version?

Comment: `os._exit` skips finally blocks, context manager `__exit__`s, exit handlers, and other important cleanup, so outside of a few highly specific cases (I believe most of them involve `fork`), it's not a good idea to use it. Also, your first code snippet still tries to do `except not SystemExit`.

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry, saved now. Regarding the ` _exit()` function, OP said he wanted a method to prevent an exception being raised. I guess I will mention the harms of it in my answer though.